# Purpose of root in LayoutInflater

Tags: java, android, android-layout

As per my understanding,

LayoutInflater.inflate(resource, root, attachToRoot):- It's job is JUST to convert the XML to the Views object.

My question is, since inflate() is not concerned with `root` parameter if we are passing `attachToRoot = false`, then can we use `LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view, null, false)` without any blunder?

The reasoning behind the above is, `getView(..)` is only responsible for returning the dynamic view which is constructed according to the position, it isn't responsible for attaching this constructed View to the parent ViewGroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root view can also affect the layout. The inflated view can be sized and positioned relative to its parent (for example, `match_parent` size param), and the root view parameter works as the parent for layout purposes even if the view doesn't (yet) get added to it.